# Adobe Edge: unload Composition

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-edge

reference: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/edgeanimate/api/current/index.html#multiplecompositions

So, If this loads a compostion...

```
AdobeEdge.loadComposition('comp1js', 'comp1DivClass', {
scaleToFit: "none",
centerStage: "both",
bScaleToParent: true/*,
htmlRoot: "folderNameIfInAnotherDir/"*/
}, {"dom":[]}, {"dom":[]});
```

what then unloads it?
Can anyone help. I would like to load and remove at will.

Comment: Did you finally solve this problem?